# How to pass ID of a dynamically generated button to action method?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I created a Facelets page. In the page dynamically generated some buttons, each button has a ID,
When submitted the event, I want to pass a button's ID to the action.(button is dynamically)

But i don't know how to pass dynamic parameters in JSF.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the button component in the action method by [`UIComponent#getCurrentComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getCurrentComponent%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29):

```
public void submit() {
    UIComponent button = UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
    String id = button.getId(); // or button.getClientId();
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, if you're targeting a Servlet 3.0 / EL 2.2 container (Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, etc), then you can just invoke methods with arguments in EL:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.submit(component.id)}" /> <!-- or component.clientId -->
```

with

```
public void submit(String id) {
    // ...
}
```